# Custom middleware causes duplicate filter to filter out all requests

Tags: scrapy

I have made a simple middleware like this (I removed all actual logic to recude possible errors)

```
class ApiMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return request
```

I've registerd in settings like this, I've tried changing the integer to various numbers to see if it fired in a ordered that collided with another middleware, but I got the same result:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'py_scrape.middleware.ApiMiddleware': 543,
}
```

The middleware is detected by scrapy successfully, but for some reason the DUP_FILTER thinks all requests are duplicates, even the first one, which should be impossible.

Log:

```
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET [url is here]> (referer: None)
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-07 10:15:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

**EDIT**

I've read some more doc's and I think this is what's happening:

1. My middleware is run. Returns request with new url.
2. Dup_filter add this request to seen urls.
3. My middleware is run again since I returned a request in the middleware.
4. Dup_filter is checked again and since the url is in seen url's it returns True.

Can't figure out a solution though.

Comment: Do all the scrapy requests have the same base URL? By that I mean is every request http://www.google.com/link1,
http://www.google.com/link2 etc ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm testing with another spider right now which should just visit one page, and it still gets filtered before anything is downloaded.
I found some doc's and I think it has something to do with that when i return a request in middleware, it will apply the middleware to that request again. But I still cant figure it out really.

Comment: Have you tried scrapy.Request(url,callback, dont_filter=True) ? Scrapy may think that each request if the base url is the same, is a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, that works. However, I'm using make a project with other developers so filtered request might be required in some spiders that use this middleware. Thanks though.

Comment: It may be helpful to know what the downloader middlewares purpose is. Generally the downloader middleware is used to do something with the request before the downloader sends the request to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, maybe not the best solution but it works. Code, if someone else has the same problem:

```
class ApiMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if request.meta.get('applied'):
            return None
        new_meta = request.meta
        new_meta['applied'] = True
        request = request.replace(
            url='<new formated url here>',
           meta=new_meta)
        return request
```